# Is Magento the right platform to sell downloadable products

Tags: catalog, server-setup, downloadable

My products are made of multiple files of approx 1GB each. Customers need to be able to download files by using a download manager. Resuming capabilities is a must, together with the possibility to download multiple files at once.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing are client-side features which would be implemented in a browser or client GUI and facilitated by the server accepting data range request headers (IIRC).

But yes, Magento is fine for selling downloads.

Comment: Yes I know that you can sell downloadable products on Magento by what u describe is a scenario where the files are delivered directly by the server without script in the middle. Open Cart doesn't allow the features I mentioned so I am trying to find out if Magento will work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about with regards to Magento. No eCommerce platform would or should provide the functionality you are describing - it's client-side software that would facilitate resuming downloads (like Amazon's downloader for example). It would be up to you to integrate some solution or service to do this, just like any third party integration. Sorry if I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: It looks like you understood since you are telling me that no ecommerce platform provides that functionality. So, do you know of any third party integration for Magento to allow download resuming and simultaneous downloads? - http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7201 This is for Open Cart.

Comment: In my opinion that extension is a bit of a pipe dream. I'd be surprised if it worked for most people out of the box (I could be wrong, but my gut tells me otherwise). I'm not aware of any Magento integration which does this. You could always buy the OpenCart extension and extract the architectural bits to create the necessary controller logic for this.

Answer (score 3):

Working with a Magento shop which deals with downloadable products I can say: Yes, Magento is the right platform to sell downloadable products.

As you have to deal with big files, this is more up to your server/PHP configuration (`upload_max_filesize`, `max_execution_time`, etc.) and not a limitation of your Magento shop.

Regarding your products including multiple files: For each product there is a setting "Links can be purchased separately".

- Set to "Yes" makes it possible for the user to select just one the file
  links to buy and download later.
- Set to "No" adds all related file links to the product bought by your customer.

Ben already answered on resuming capabilities and downloading of multiple files at once.
I don't know any extension providing this functionallity either and would also leave this up to the users chosen download manager or implement custom functionality.

Comment: I guess he is not going to upload 1GB files via Magento, but using (S)FTP for that?!

Comment: "chosen download manager or implement custom functionality" - these are two very different options and it seems to me (according to what Ben wrote) that the first option won't be an option without the second one (server/magento-side implementation)

Comment: Yes I will use FTP to send files to server.